# Vaadin display HTML content saved by RichTextArea

Tags: java, vaadin, wysiwyg, vaadin8

I want create simply WYSIWYG in Vaadin.
I have a RichTextArea component on my page, which saves value as HTML.
I use RichText(from viritin plugin, which simply extends Label) to display result of RichTextArea, but not all tags are properly displayed.
For example  `<font color="#ff0000">fdasgd</font>` or `<span style="background-color: yellow;">fdghtfjdgj</span>` isn't working, but `<b><i><u>dfsgdhfj</u></i></b>` works.
Any ideas how to properly display content saved by RichTextArea?

Comment: RichtTextArea has nothing to do with HTML, it's RTF. Use another editor to handle html content

Comment: @AndréSchild that's not true.  `com.vaadin.ui.RichTextArea` is a simple HTML-Editor.

Comment: The `RichText` from viritin is sanitizing the content. Your description by "does not work" is not accurate enough to dig deeper into that problem.  When you say, that e.g. `<font/>` is not working, does that mean, it does not get included into the label and sent to the browser or is the stylesheet preventing the color from showing up? To test for the later, you can use `Label` with `ContentMode.HTML` -- but be aware, that this is a security risk.  So subclass the `RichText` and add your own `getWhilteList` https://github.com/viritin/viritin/blob/3269a3390b6267ae005257a622dd2e53cccf6663/src/mai

Comment: @cfrick content is pased to Label(yes, I try ContentMode.HTML), but probably browser preventing showing up the color or font, even if I comment all my custom css.